# Problem with Google Cloud App Engine and Spring Boot gradle Deploying

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a problem..
I want to deploy my Spring Boot Gradle app to GC App Engine.
I use the command :

**gradle appengineDeploy**

It actually works but when i try to open the app in the browser it says :

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

So the app was deployed successfully but it has a problem to start..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart (ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:330)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1406)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:522)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:240)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:178)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:120)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:728)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:691)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:661)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:853)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate (ConstructorResolver.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run (SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext (SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup (SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup (SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup (ContainerInitializer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart (ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate (ConstructorResolver.java:622)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.setApplicationName (CoreSocketFactory.java:341)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.cloudSqlDataSourceProperties (GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java:209)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb6c42e.CGLIB$cloudSqlDataSourceProperties$0 (<generated>)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb6c42e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a426c72d.invoke (<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb6c42e.cloudSqlDataSourceProperties (<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

So it is caused by

```
Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
```

my build.gradle looks like this

````
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.+'    // Latest 1.x.x releas
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks

group = 'de.msm'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = 1.8     // App Engine Flexible uses Java 8


configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}



appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
        promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    }
}
/*
Only for Run
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}*/

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    jcenter{
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}

task getHomeDir { //To get actual homeDir
    doLast {
        println gradle.gradleHomeDir
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:0.17.2'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.56'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.1.7.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.0.0'
    compile 'io.rest-assured:xml-path:4.0.0'
    compile 'io.rest-assured:json-path:4.0.0'
    testCompile 'io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:4.0.0'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.5.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'
    compile group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf', version: '9.1.18'
    compile "org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:2.0.3"
    compile "com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.10"
    compile "com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.10"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.15"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.15"
    compile "xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.8.0-beta4"
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-storage', version: '1.91.0'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql', version: '1.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:+'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

}
```

I dont understand whats the problem..
````

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible? Does it run on your local environment?

Comment: @OliverAragon I try running it local with gradle appengineRun task. It should be standard.

Comment: Did it work on you local environment?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I'm using maven and this error only happens when i run as test.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same issue myself right now.