# SpringBoot Dev tools giving error during hot deployment Failed to instantiate DataSource

Tags: spring

My pom.xml has enabled with spring-boot-devtools true . My application is using google cloud postgres.

Dev tools Hot deployment is enabled in pom.xml.

During the first time start application runs without any issues.
But during hot deployment (when changing java files), it is getting failed with the below exception  -

```
2021-03-08 08:46:29.449 ERROR 94877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.<>SpringApp.main(SpringApp.java:26) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set ApplicationName - SQLAdmin client already initialized.
```

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113844/problem-with-google-cloud-app-engine-and-spring-boot-gradle-deploying

Comment: Nope.Mine is regarding Hot Deployment.

Comment: Any suggestions ?